# Opa: higher order function application

Tags: lambda, arguments, opa, higher-order-functions, thunk

In Opa, it is possible to partially apply functions. However, I would like to supply a function with all its arguments, and return a function taking no arguments. For example:

```
function make-thunk(f, a) { function() { f(a) } }
```

The code above works fine, but it has one problem: It is only suited for functions taking exactly one argument. I am curious whether it is possible in Opa to make the above more generic, so the function can be used for functions of arbitrary arity.

I was unable to find information about apply- (scheme) or call- (prolog) like functions on the Opa API, forum, IRC, Github or SO, so here I am hoping I missed something, somewhere. ;-) (There were some traces of an @lazy keyword, but no explanation or documentation so I didn't keep a reference, sorry.)

To further clarify / illustrate: If Opa were scheme, I'd write the following code:

```
(define (make-thunk f . args)
  (lambda () (apply f args)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to `make-thunk` then you have to use a tuple:

```
function f((a,b,c)) {
   ...
}

args = ("a","b","c")
make-thunk(f, args)
```

Btw, where did you find mentions to `@lazy`?

Comment: @lazy was probably mentioned on IRC, as I don't find relevant links in my browser history :-)